# Salesforce Data entry source for child business unit journeys

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

Just wanted to make sure I was thinking about this the right way. If we are creating journeys in a child business unit, if we want to leverage our MC Connect data, we will have to utilize the Salesforce data via shared data extensions from the parent or can we use Salesforce Data as our entry source even for child business unit journeys? I ask because I keep running into errors trying to implement Salesforce Data as an entry source for the child business units.

Thoughts?

Comment: Unless you are using multi-org MC Connect (which by what you wrote I assume you’re not doing) you will have to populate data from Parent to a Shared DE to use it in a Child BU

Comment: Thank you, that's what I figured. My understanding of multi-org was that it was meant to connect a single org to separate instances of MC and not necessarily to be individual BUs. Multi-org would allow child BUs direct access to SF data?

Comment: Yes, you can have different Salesforce System Users, with access to different data sets, connected to different BUs. Or, different orgs connected to different BUs - see here: https://dreamevent.secure.force.com/articleView?id=mc_co_multi_org_scenario_examples.htm&type=5

Comment: To clarify - Are you refererring to "Salesforce Data"  Entry events?  the data you get from synchronized or shared data extensions would always be "data extension" type entry sources, wouldn't they? For the latter, you indeed need to have them shared from the parent to utilize in Journey Builder. Which comes down to a latency question, the data might be <1 hour delayed through the sharing automation. For the former, "Salesforce Data" Entry events, aka event listeners, you should be able to operate from the child BU in the default setup as well.

Comment: Thanks Jonas, yes I'm referring to Salesforce Data Entry Sources in the Child BU. If the functionality is there to work then I must not have my settings configured correctly since I have visibility errors with my Salesforce objects from within the Child BU journeys. I'll take a look to see if I'm missing anything. Thanks!